# Python class - create instance of nested dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to create class that will take a dictionary as input, and then that be used as input to the same class (effectively creating a nested dictionary with class methods):

Here is what I have so far:

```
class popl(object):
        def __init__(self,d):
            self.__dict__= d

dic = {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}
# Inner dict
inner = popl(dic)
```

Now I can do: `inner.x` to access the elements.
Then I want to be able to create a new dictionary `outer` consisting of `inner`, and access the elements as: `outer.inner.x`

I tried:

```
outer=popl(inner)
```

but I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'popl'
```

Any idea how to achieve what I want? Do I need a nested class instead?

Comment: What would be the key of the "outer" dict that would contain the inner dict? What is the need for this extra class? You can already create nested dictionaries without the overhead of an object.

Comment: ``popl`` takes a dictionary, not a ``popl`` object. How should ``popl(inner)`` know that ``inner`` is the value for the key ``"inner"``?

Comment: @gallen The key for the outer dictionary will be "inner". And now `x` should be accessible by `outer.inner.x`. The reason for all that is it is cleaner than typing outer['inner']['x']

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok, I am really new to python! Sorry if my question is kind of silly! How do I make `popl(inner)` with key `inner` then?

Comment: As an aside, don't do `self.__dict__= d`, this breaks a pretty useful optimization (shared-key namespace dicts...). Instead, use `self.__dict__.update(d)` Also, no a nested class wouldn't help here at all. They really serve no purpose other than perhaps to keep one class in another classes namespace, but they don't really provide any functionality in and of themselves

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question would be:

```
class popl(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, popl):
            self.__dict__ = { "inner": d.__dict__ }
        else:
            self.__dict__ = d

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)


dic = {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}
# Inner dict
inner = popl(dic)

outer = popl(inner)
print(outer)

# Output
>>> {'inner': {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but when I do: `print(outer.inner.x)` I am getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: That sort of accessor is for attributes (as noted by the error), which are only on classes/objects. Dictionaries are a structure all their own and therefore don't have support for accessing that way. To get what you are asking, you would need to create a custom class that could dynamically allow attribute access for unknown keys, which is totally unnecessary. Your best solution is to find a way to utilize dictionaries as they exist, rather than creating a whole new class around a built-in structure. The syntax of `dict[key][key]` is expected behavior for Python, changing it is ill-advised.

Comment: I agree that `object.attribute` is accessing an attribute of the `object` class. I guess I have to come up with a class to essentially do the following:

`dic = {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}
inner = popl(dic)
outer={'inner':inner}
outer=popl(outer)`

Comment: "I guess I have to come up with a class...". I don't see the reason for doing so. What is the purpose, other than personal aesthetics, for wanting to completely reinvent the wheel for working with dictionaries?

Comment: Would addict ( https://github.com/mewwts/addict ) be of use in this case? /jim